# Why defalut value from getDefaultProps func overrides the value passed from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Recently i am attempting to transform a native page to a React-native page for my App. I encountered a puzzled problem with usage of `getDefaultProps` func. As far as i know, the func will work when no value passed in from parent component and also caches value sometimes. But when i have passed `isSuccess` with `false` and defalut value has been set `true`, i got this property as `true`. Has anyone tells me why and the specific function of `getDefalutProps`?

Code likes below.

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
            displayData: {},
            bottomStyle: 0,
            isSuccess: true
        };
  },

render: function(){
        // isSuccess is true
        console.log("trade state: ", this.props.isSuccess);
```

Thx a lot.

Comment: How are you passing the prop? It's definitely being passed as a boolean and not a string, i.e. `isSuccess={false}` as opposed to `isSuccess="false"`

Comment: I passed the prop with false, boolean not the string.

Comment: My negligence. I passed the `isSuccess` in dataSource object not in props. Therefore got the defalut boolean value. Thx...